# Laravel get created_at value in model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch the created_at attribute in the model so I can put it in my relationship.

E.g. rows in `exit_accession_goods` created today should look at rows in `entry_accession_goods` that were made today or before it.

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExitAccessionGood extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['exit_accession_id', 'norm_id', 'quantity'];

    public function entry_goods()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EntryAccessionGood', 'norm_id', 'norm_id')
        ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $this->created);
    }

    public function packagings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PackagingItem', 'norm_id', 'norm_id');
    }

    public function getCreatedAttribute()
    {
        return "{$this->created_at}";
    }
}
```

The `$this->created` returns an empty string.

Comment: Please share more details - there is no `$this->created` in your code. Additionally, have you checked whether the database contains that column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function getCreatedAttribute(){
    return $this->attributes['created_at'];
}
```